# Mysql select query where column has two values

Tags: mysql

I have a table in `MySQL`. In this I have columna called `device` and `test_Id`.

```
+-------+---------+
|test_id|   device|
+-------+---------+
| test_1|   Win PC|
| test_1|     Xbox|
| test_2|  Windows|
| test_3|   Win PC|
+-------+---------+
```

I want to select `test_Id` where `device` is both `Win PC` and `Xbox`. I have done like below

```
select test_id from table where device in ('Win PC', 'Xbox');
```

I am getting below result.

```
+----------+
| test_id  |
+----------+
| test_1   |
| test_3   |
| test_1   |
+----------+
```

But I want the result to be like

```
+----------+
| test_id  |
+----------+
| test_1   |
| test_1   |
+----------+
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you trying two `AND`s?

Comment: Would 1 result suffice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest query to achieve the result, a distinct list of test_id:

```
SELECT t.test_id 
  FROM mytable t 
 WHERE t.device IN ('Win PC','Xbox') 
 GROUP BY t.test_id
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.device) = 2
```

If we want to return individual rows, we could use that as an inline view, and do a JOIN to the outer table. Something like this:

```
SELECT d.test_id 
  FROM ( SELECT t.test_id 
           FROM mytable t 
          WHERE t.device IN ('Win PC','Xbox') 
          GROUP BY t.test_id
          HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.device) = 2
       ) q
  JOIN mytable d 
    ON d.test_id = q.test_id
 WHERE d.device IN ('Win PC','Xbox')
```

Another alternative would be use EXISTS correlated subqueries

```
 SELECT d.test_id
   FROM mytable d
  WHERE d.device IN ('Win PC','Xbox')
    AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM mytable t1
                  WHERE t1.test_id = d.test_id
                    AND t1.device = 'Win PC'
               )
    AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM mytable t2
                  WHERE t2.test_id = d.test_id
                    AND t2.device = 'Xbox'
               )
```

There are other query patterns that will achieve equivalent results.

Comment: Couldn't you just eliminate `d.device IN ('Win PC','Xbox')` in last alternative?

Comment: @revo, yes, we could remove that condition. Then the return from the query would be different if we had rows `(1,'Win PC'),(1,'Xbox'),(1,'Android')`, the query would return three rows, instead of two. We can write it either way, it really depends on the specification, what the query is supposed to return. (Simplest would be return just distinct values of `test_id` (the first query). When we want to return individual rows, then the specification is more blurry at the edges.)

Comment: Yes, good point.

Answer (score 2):

```
select test_id 
from table 
where device = 'Win PC'
AND test_id IN (SELECT test_id 
from table 
where device = 'Xbox')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know whether a test_id has both an Xbox and PC, you can do the following:

```
select test_id from 
   (select test_id, count(test_id) as cnt 
    from table 
    where device in ('Win PC', 'Xbox'), group by test_id) 
where cnt > 1
```

Comment: MySQL requires the derived table be assigned an alias. In the case where we aren't guaranteed that `(test_id,device)` tuple is unique, consider the return with two (or more) duplicate rows `('test_2','Win PC')` and no `('test_2','Xbox')` row.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it but you should try this query

```
SELECT table_pc.test_id 
FROM table AS table_pc 
INNER JOIN table AS table_xb ON (table_xb.test_id = table_pc.test_id)
WHERE table_pc.device = 'Win PC' 
AND table_xb.devide = 'Xbox'
GROUP BY table_pc.test_id
```